# RegQueryValueEx returns 2 at installation, but by restarting the service it returns ERROR_SUCCESS (0)

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm trying reading the Registry data from a value named **Scoop** in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Company\Software\Settings`:

[image]

This key and value already exist prior to installing my software.

My software contains its own 32-bit service. So when my software is installed, the service (running under SYSTEM), attempts to read this value.

However, within the service, RegQueryValueEx returns "2" (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). Yet, when I run services.msc and restart my service, RegQueryValueEx returns "0" (ERROR_SUCCESS). RegOpenKeyEx always returns ERROR_SUCCESS, but RegQueryValueEx is returning 2 at installation.

My code:

```
HANDLE hKey = NULL;
WCHAR *sPath = L"SOFTWARE\\Company\\Software\\Settings";
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath, 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);  
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwType = 0;
WCHAR sZeroLengthString[4] = {0};
// get the buffer size needed, including null terminating characters.
dwRV = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, L"Scoop", NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE) sZeroLengthString, &dwSize);
```

The instalation is being run under a domain admin account.

I can't for the life of me figure out why RegQueryValueEx is returning 2 at install, but is fine restarting with services.msc. The manifest of the service is set to `highestAvailable`, and there are no special permissions on the Registry key, just the standard...SYSTEM does have `Full Control`.

Comment: As you are running as 32-bit `Wow6432Node` will be remapped see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry

Answer (score 0):

Do not access the `Wow6432Node` key directly at all, pretend it doesn't even exist. Access the non-redirected key normally, using the appropriate `KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY` flag to handle the redirection based on which view your want to access. This is even stated in the documentation:

[Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)

> Redirected keys are mapped to physical locations under `Wow6432Node`. For example, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` is redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node`. **However, the physical location of redirected keys should be considered reserved by the system. Applications should not access a key's physical location directly, because this location may change**. For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view).

`Wow6432Node` is an *implementation detail* of the WOW64 emulator for 32bit processes. So, don't rely on it. Simply drop `Wow6432Node` from your `sPath` since you are explicitly accessing the 32bit Registry view:

```
HANDLE hKey = NULL;
LPCWSTR sPath = L"SOFTWARE\\Company\\Software\\Settings";
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath, 0, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);  
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwType = 0;
WCHAR sZeroLengthString[4] = {0};
// get the buffer size needed, including null terminating characters.
dwRV = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, L"Scoop", NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE) sZeroLengthString, &dwSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Remy. My mistake. The code actually does not have Wow6432Node in the path. I just put Wow6432Node in because that's where the values are stored. I corrected the code. The same problem is happening though. At install, RegQueryValueEx returns 2.

Comment: @JeffR "*I just put Wow6432Node in because that's where the values are stored*" - that is because RegEdit is showing you the 64bit view of the Registry. In any case, I would suggest using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch the Registry during install and service startup, see if there is any difference in how keys are being accessed.